# Select2 - Disable options under other optgroups when option under one optgroup is chosen

Tags: javascript, meteor, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 in Meteor. I have a dropdown with inspections(appointments) grouped by date under an optgroup. When I select an inspection I would like to disable inspections on any other days from being selected. So only inspections on the same day can be selected. I have the options disabled, but I can't get the list to stay open, and also I get errors any time a selection is made. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. This is what I have:

Html:

```
select(name='inspectionId' id='inspections-js' class='form-control' multiple='multiple' required)
```

Javascript:

```
Template.reportsNew.rendered = ->
   $('#inspections-js').select2(closeOnSelect: false)


'change #inspections-js': (e)->
   # Disable options not on the same day as the selected option.
   selectedOptGroup = $(e.target).select2().find(':selected').parent('optgroup')
   otherOptGroups = $(e.target).find('optgroup').not(selectedOptGroup)
   $(otherOptGroups).find('option').prop('disabled', true)
```

Error on option select:

```
natestrauser_select2.js:853 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

[image]

Comment: Due to a bug in Select2's caching, the `disabled` property is cached from the first time the dropdown is opened. As a result, it won't properly switch the disabled state of options after that.

Comment: Thanks @KevinBrown that is good to know. So there is no standard for disabling/enabling options after the select box has been rendered? That is depressing.

Comment: It's something we plan to fix in the upcoming 4.0.1 release, and I'll create an answer here tomorrow about how you can work around it for now.

Comment: @KevinBrown thanks an immense amount. I was in the middle of writing a custom solution but it would be great to stick with Select2.

Comment: [Here's the ticket on Select2 about this issue.](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3347) It's actually not clear where the error is coming from, are you able to reproduce this in [a jsbin](http://jsbin.com) or within a Stack Snippet?

Comment: I haven't reproduced it in a jsbin no. I can if that would help to track it down.